# Jmeter - Err in response body when send body data from external file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, blazemeter

I have a scenario to send data in the request body from external file in `jmeter` and when I send it, I have got the **ERR** in the response body. Here is my post method request body:

```
${__FileToString(/Users/public/${__eval(${validUrls})}.txt,,)} 

Response:
POST data:
```

**ERR**
Please help why I can not send data from `external file`.
Anis

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your function syntax, just make sure that:

1. Your `validUrls` JMeter Variable has the anticipated value (you can check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination)
2. The user which is running JMeter has read access to the files under `Users/public/` folder
3. The file is being properly read and sent (look at Request -> Request Body) tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, if you see `**ERR**` there - it means that your function fails somewhere somehow, the reason of failure can be found in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. validUrls has a value and I have corrected Users/public/ folder to uppercase because it public was lowercase and read access is gone. Still I have the same issue.